# Facebook share url with query strings

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharepoint-2013

I have the following problem in Sharing pages from my website through Facebook.
When I try to Share a complicated URL that containing a lot of query strings and their values using Graph API or Sharer.php or Sharing button, Facebook neglects the query string and omits them. As an example 
Sharing this URL http://beta.egypt.gov.eg/en/Services/Pages/ServiceDescription.aspx?servID=578&catID=1&subID=666 which has been shared through many ways:

1-  Through Sharer.php
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.egypt.gov.eg%2Fen%2FServices%2FPages%2FServiceDescription.aspx%3FservID%3D578%26catID%3D1%26subID%3D666&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fs2.postimg.org%2Fubp1gef6d%2Fbawaba_logo.png&p%5Btitle%5D=Bawaba&p%5Bsummary%5D=+Check+our+new+Government+Portal+now+and+get+to+know+to+our+new+services  ; Generates error cause all query strings and their values are deleted after sharing.

2-  Through Facebook Share Button and embedding the code in my website; Also the same problem happened.

When I debug my url using Facebook debugger ,It gives me the canonical URL without any query string.

Are there any way to share the URL link exactly as it is with its query strings and their values or a way to control the Canonical URL or og:url , Image og:Image, Title og:title, and description og:description, while Sharing any page.

Comment: _“When I debug my url using Facebook debugger ,It gives me the canonical URL without any query string.”_ – well that’s because what Facebook uses to determine the “final” or “real” URL. If you don’t want that parameter-less version to be used – then _don’t_ specify it as the canonical URL. (OR use an `og:url` meta tag to specify the parameter version as the “real” URL of that object for Facebook.)